# Java 8 Update 91 blocks applet

Tags: java, applet

I am not able to run any applet with Java 8 Update 91.
I everytime get following message: 
**Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an 
expired or not yet valid certificate from running**.
This message appears despite inclusion the website into Exception Site List.
Can somebody give me any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Applet is a deprecated technology, and it's actually a bit sad to see Java blocking its own creation.  One option would be to keep an earlier JDK 8 or 7 around to use for running your applet.

Comment: applet and jdbc and some more features are no more part of `Java V1.8`

Comment: Did you restart your browser? I was able to run https://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/clock after adding that URL to the exception site list, and restarting the browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I restarted firefox version 46.0.1.

Comment: Did you sign your applet with  an official certificate?